# How to stop playing a Sound via Soundpool?

Tags: android, soundpool

Please, have a look at those pieces of code:

```
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;

soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.batimanbailedosenxutos, 1);
```

and when I press the button:

```
soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

if I press this button twice in the same time, it plays the sound togheter, I want to stop the sound and play again if the user press the button while playing

I tryed puting an

```
soundPool.stop(soundID);
```

before the soundPool.play but I don't know why it only work for the 1 time the song is played, do you guys have any ideia why this works only for the 1 time? and how I can solve this?  thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The method `stop()` takes the stream ID of a currently playing stream, not the sound ID you have loaded.  So something like this:

```
int streamId = soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);

soudPool.stop(streamId);
streamId = soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Would stop the currently playing track and start another.  A second option would be to limit the number of streams your `SoundPool` allows.  If you instantiate your `SoundPool` with a `maxStreams` value of 1, then any currently playing sound will stop when you attempt to start another, which may implement your desired behavior more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You Can See Code

```
public static void clear() {
        if (mSoundManager != null) {
            mSoundManager.mSoundPool = null;
            mSoundManager.mAudioManager = null;
            mSoundManager.mSoundPoolMap = null;
        }
        mSoundManager = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by loading the soundpool track id again..

```
mSoundPool.Stop(trackID);
trackID.load(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.audioclip,1;
```

And you can again play the mSoundPool.play() anyWhere.