# How to disable sounds

Tags: java, android

I am creating a casual game. And I applied sounds when the button is clicked etc.. now I have an image button of speaker icon. I Want to disable the sounds when It is pressed. how do I do that?

```html
I used sound pool here is my sound loop class:


public class SoundPool {
    private static SoundPool soundpool;
    private static int clicksound;
    private static int gameosound;
    private static int scoreupsound;

    public SoundPlayer (Context context) {

        soundpool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        clicksound = soundpool.load(context,R.raw.click, 1);
        gameosound= soundpool.load(context,R.raw.gameover, 1);
        scoreupsound = soundpool.load(context,R.raw.score, 1);
    }


    public void playclicksound() {
        soundpool.play(clicksound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    }

    public void playgameosound() {
        soundpool.play(gameosound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    }

    public void playscoreupsound() {
        soundpool.play(scoreupsound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    }


}
```

```html
        public class MainActivity {
        private TextView word1;
        private ImageButton speakericon;/* I want to change image when     pressed*/
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             word1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word1);
            
             word1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sound.playclicksound(); /* I want to cancel this                   sound when the speaker icon is pressed */
             });
            }
```

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694110/how-to-stop-playing-a-sound-via-soundpool?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and add inside:

```
soundpool.pause();
```

or

```
soundpool.stop();
```

Something like this:

```
public void stopclicksound() {
        soundpool.stop();
    }
```

Comment: I also want to change the speaker icon when pressed. do I have to use an Image switcher?

Comment: You can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089300/how-can-i-change-the-image-of-an-imageview

Comment: I want the image button to change when preesed. your link is completely different

Comment: I gave you an example, on how to change an image. You can implement it however you would like it. Here is how you can click on an image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326601/android-imageview-on-click

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar I don't know your exact implementation. In order for `sound.sop()` to work, it has to be started already. Otherwise, it will give an error. I usually check if it has been started, before running `.stop()` function. But it works, I can assure you. You can see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html and here as well: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()